# Converting raw bytes from octet-stream to image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to display an image in javascript from an octet stream. On another system, the images are saved in 10000 image single binary files, and my front-end is grabbing the image data using offsets, meaning I grab sometimes the middle image (5000) to display. So this data is raw, it was formed from writing bytes directly. I know the height and width of the image (200 and 720 respectively) in 8-bit grayscale format.

How can I read this data into an image and display it, here is my current attempt

```
downloadImage(img_id: number): void {
    var range = "bytes=" + img_id * 144000 + "-" + ((img_id + 1) * 144000 - 1);
    fetch(this.signedUrl, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Range: range,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.blob();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const img = new Image();

        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);

        // newer promise based version of img.onload
        img.onload = () => {
          console.log("Image decoded");
          this.currentImage = img;
        };

        img.onerror = (error) => {
          console.log("Error: ", error);
        };
```

this will always trigger the "onerror" callback, and I am not sure what the error is since its not clear to me from the console log.

edit: here is what the blob looks like using a filereader:

"data:application/octet-stream;base64,end7dnZ4eHl3eHp4eXl......"

Comment: Maybe you should at the imageData Api if you need to use use raw pixel data https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData

Comment: What do you mean by the console.log is not clear ? Do you have an error message ?